# How to treat textfield as integer field while adding sorting in views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a textfield in my content type. It have values like `1, 2, 3, ..., 10`. While I adding sorting it sorts the content `like 1, 10, 2, ...`

I can write the custom handler for it, But how can I treat it as integer in sorting while adding a query. Currently sort handler implements the following query :

```
$this->query->add_orderby($this->table_alias, $this->real_field, $this->options['order']);
```

What change I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by adding a custom handler and used [CAST Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html) of mysql and changing the query to :

```
$this->query->add_orderby(NULL, 'CAST(' . $this->real_field . ' AS SIGNED)', $this->options['order']);
```